# Django: How to load related model objects when instantiating a model

Tags: django, model

I have two related models (1-n). From the parent model, I am doing a lot of operations on the child model. For each operation I am calling:

```
ItensOrder.objects.filter(order=self.pk)
```

Inside the Order class, which is the parent, I am using the children objects several times, like this:

```
def total(self):
    itens = ItensOrder.objects.filter(order=self.pk)
    valor = sum(Counter(item.price * item.quantity for item in itens))
    return str(valor)

def details(self):
    itens = ItensOrder.objects.filter(order=self.pk)
    return format_html_join('\n', "{} ({} x {} = {})<br/>", 
                            ((item.item.name,str(item.quantity),item.price,str(item.price * item.quantity)) for item in itens))
```

What is the best way to load the related objects ONLY ONCE, so I can avoid reaching the database every time I need the related objects.

I've been trying this on the parent model:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.pk is not None:
        self.itens = ItensOrder.objects.filter(order=self.pk)
    else:
        self.itens = None
```

But this is wrong....

Anybody can help please!?

Comment: There is no need to load the related items when instantiating the parent, can you provide the code that does the operations on the child model?

Comment: @Iain, I've updated the question with more code. I am filtering the children objects more than once. I would like to avoid that.

Answer (score 2):

You can access related child objects by using the related_name of a `ForeignKey` field

```
order = Order.objects.get(id=1)
itens = order.itensorder_set.all()
```

This reverse relationship attribute will by default be the model name lowercase followed by "_set", you can change this by setting [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) on the foreign key

You can pre-populate this property with a cache of all the related objects by using [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

```
order = Order.objects.prefetch_related('itensorder_set').get(id=1)
order.itensorder_set.all()  # This can be called multiple times but will not hit the database
```

In your case

```
class Order(models.Model):

    def total(self):
        valor = sum(Counter(item.price * item.quantity for item in self.itensorder_set.all()))
        return str(valor)

    def details(self):
        return format_html_join('\n', "{} ({} x {} = {})<br/>", 
                        ((item.item.name,str(item.quantity),item.price,str(item.price * item.quantity)) for item in self.itensorder_set.all()))
```

and in your model admin override `get_queryset`

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    return super().get_queryset(request).prefetch_related('itensorder_set')
```

Comment: Should I use Order.objects.prefetch_related('itensorder_set').get(id=1) in the __init__ method? The id will be self.id.

Comment: No you should not override the init method at all. In the view that is loading the order instance you should use prefetch_related and in your functions you loop over `self.itensorder_set.all()`

Comment: I am not using any views. I am working only with admin. This code should be only inside the model.py

Comment: Okay, update my answer with some code for you. Use prefetch_related in your model admin

Comment: Thanks @Iain, but in my case I am accessing the model from an API built with Tastypie. Is there any way to accomplish this task inside the model, in the parent class?

Comment: Add prefetch_related to the queryset in your modelresource

Answer (score 0):

you can user select_related inside your functions

```
def total(self):
  itens = ItensOrder.objects.select_related('order').filter(order=self)
  valor = sum(Counter(item.price * item.quantity for item in itens))
  return str(valor)

def details(self):
   itens = ItensOrder.objects.select_related('order').filter(order=self)
   return format_html_join('\n', "{} ({} x {} = {})<br/>", 
  ((item.item.name,str(item.quantity),item.price,str(item.price * item.quantity)) for item in itens))
```